# Apperance of WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview

I am using a web-view in my app. It works just fine. However the contents appear to be docked in some frame. I want the contents to appear as they do while using some other browser.

This is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="tiwari.miet.in.lifeinadarkreflection.WebViewActivity">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webViewId">

</WebView>
```

This is the java code snippet:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewId);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings=myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String url="https://lifeinadarkreflection.wordpress.com/";
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: "However the contents appear to be docked in some frame" -- please explain what you mean by this. Also, you may wish to consider uploading a screenshot somewhere and linking to it from your question.

Comment: I have got a solution to the problem, by setting the paddings to 0dp.i.e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```